# Why will the opacity not change on this image I turned into a sprite node?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I'm making a space runner star ship game that shoots meteors. You have 4 lives and I want this image to hover over my ship and fade in opacity the fewer lives you have. I've tried the `.alpha` property but the image stays the same. Mask is the name of the sprite node.

```
func setupGame(_ size: CGSize) {
    let ship = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Spaceship.png")
    ship.position = CGPoint (x: size.width/2.0, y: size.height/2.0)
    ship.size = CGSize(width: 40.0, height: 40.0)
    ship.name = SpaceshipNodeName
    addChild(ship)

    let mask = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: shield)
    mask.position = CGPoint (x: ship.size.width/6, y: ship.size.height/6)
    mask.size = CGSize(width: 40.0, height: 40.0)
    mask.alpha = 0.5

    ship.addChild(mask)
```

Comment: You've checked that the shield image itself is OK (e.g., put it off to the side so you can see it)? If so, perhaps you have `ignoresSiblingOrder` set to `true` in the view, and then there's no guarantee about the order of drawing except for depth.  Try setting `mask.zPosition=1` to ensure that the child is drawn above the parent.

Comment: you need to show more code. I don't believe that zPosition has anything to do with it. but there might be a possibility that the alpha is being reset somewhere else in code. search the page for alpha and see if there are any other locations where it is set and put a breakpoint on it